# Decompile .EXE - Created w/ PyInstaller

Tags: python, version

So I've found a few resources on the internet, but I'm running into trouble with the version numbers. Apparently there were some "major" changes to some aspects of Python between versions 3.7 and 3.10? Since the file I'm attempting to decompile back into readable code is some years old (just happened to run across it and wanted to improve on it now that I've progressed my Python knowledge somewhat).

I'm not entirely sure there's a way around this or not, but perhaps I'm doing something wrong. I attempted to use decompyle6 ... which is where I'm running into the version issue. I suppose the most obvious answer would be to go back through the archives, install the older Python version, and decompile from IT?

Comment: ... unrelated note, would I be wrong in providing feedback suggesting that being unable to add more accurate and specific tags for posted questions doesn't seem to be a productive restriction. Needing 1500 reputation to add what is basically the equivalent to a hash tag? Is there a reason for that I'm not understanding?

Comment: I understand that you're frustrated, but please avoid profanity here. The word you used was relatively mild, but please keep your language professional.

Comment: On your tag comment, this is not the right place for that feedback. But see these posts on meta for some context: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404893/354577, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/354577, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254943/354577.